# Connect an SSD to an old MotherBoard ASRock K7S41GX

Tags: ssd, adapter

I have an old desktop running Linux, and I would like to put a SSD in as my main drive (replacing the current HDD).

The idea is to speed up the computer by placing the OS and applications in the SSD. I'm looking to buy a 120-250 GB, SATA3 SSD and some type of connector/adapter (like IDE/PATA to SATA) so it works with my current motherboard. Sometime later I will upgrade other parts (motherboard, cpu, ram) or transfer this drive to another computer.

Some of the Hardware being used :

- CPU: AMD ATHLON XP 1900+
- MotherBoard: [ASRock K7S41GX](http://www.asrock.com/mb/sis/k7s41gx/)
- PSU: Power Supply ATX12V Pentium IV & PFC LC6550

Because this is more of a intermediate upgrade, I would like to spend on the connector (or other solution) as little as possible. It has to make sense from a purchase point of view, otherwise making the full upgrade would be a better choice (And probably this is the only solution in this case).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would really think twice about purchasing an SSD for this system. You are not going to get anywhere near the performance increases you are thinking.

Comment: @Cfinley I think you are making to many wrong assumptions about my question, this in fact an Hardware recommendation. I don't have a trouble in the hardware, I don't think I will get more speed. What I would like is a Hardware recommendation for this intermediary upgrade. And I need help finding a specific product for my needs. I also updated the question, hoping this is more clear to every one. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. While your question is not a tech support question anymore, it is still too broad for us to reopen. I now understand that you are looking for a SATA SSD for your system, but you do not state the storage size and the price you want to stay under. If you can add both of those to your question, I will reopen it for you.

Comment: @Cfinley Really? …I edit the question with more information like you asked, except for the actual price (because let's face it, in which currency? And with or without shipping costs?) and placed more meaningful information related to that (I think). I guess that the ideia is to receive recommendations, not limit to much a possible good answer (even one that most is not expecting). Hopping this is sufficient (otherwise let it be closed), Thanks!

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you would want an SSD is this system. This system is so old that it just doesn't make sense. You'd be much better off spending $20-25 to get a older cheap prebuild and then sticking an SSD in that.

Comment: This is enthusiast think, if it is possible and and how possible it is. But I understand the questions and comments. Thanks!

Comment: A challenge if you will I guess, but probably not desirable or functional like @CDove said! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes.  Desirable or functional....now that's a question.

Your motherboard only supports IDE/PATA connected drives.  This is the traditional "ribbon" cable connection.  This means you will need an IDE/PATA cable-connected drive, like this one:

[https://www.amazon.com/128GB-KingSpec-2-5-inch-SM2236-Controller/dp/B0091T4ZWU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091T4ZWU)

Please note that the price of this one piece of hardware is worth more than the entire rest of the rig combined, and it's still only just over $80 USD for 128GB.  You're also limited to PATA IDE communication speeds, hamstringing the SSD.  If you're just an enthusiast and like to keep up old machines, it might be worth it to you, but I recommend looking into a new mobo, processor, and RAM if this is your only computer.

Comment: Somebody makes an IDE SSD? Why? You can find [modern IDE HDDs](https://www.amazon.com/Blue-320-Desktop-Hard-Drive/dp/B000RO3BPA/ref=sr_1_54?ie=UTF8&qid=1526660628&sr=8-54&keywords=ide%2Bhdd&th=1) that will be just as fast, have more storage, and be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks! So, this is not my only computer! And this solution is expensive and not very desirable like you said. So, the ideia was to buy a modern SSD Drive (SATA) for the time being and then make a bigger upgrade (like: motherboard, cpu, ram). Using some some type of connector to make the IDE/PATA to SATA.

Comment: That's not really a thing.   Even if you could connect in this way, you'd be slowing things down to IDE speeds.  The combination of drive and adapter, if it did exist, would cost more than the one in the link here, and would also put you in the exact same performance hole.  Your alternative might be a SCSI card and drive, but this would probably be even more expensive and hard to find now.

Comment: @CDove Just letting you know the question has changed in a way that affects your answer.